# Laravel + Inertia + Vue Js -> cant accsess to hasMany attributes

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, has-many, inertiajs

im new to Laravel, Inertiy and Vue JS. I have to setup a project with them, which works really cool.

Now i have a problem. I have a few games and every game hasMany ads. If i get the Games with something like:

```
$games = Game::where(['id' => auth()->user()->current_team_id])->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->with('theAds')->get();
```

in Game.php:

```
  /**
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function theAds(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TheAds::class);
    }
```

in TheAds.php:

```
/**
 * @return BelongsTo
 */
public function game()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Game::class);
}
```

Now, if i var_dump($games[x]['theAds']->count()) it dumps the corrrect count for each game. But if i use it in Game.vue like this:

```
<tr v-for="(game, i) in $page.props.games" :key="game.id">
    <td class="text-center">{{ game.name }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ game.theAds }}</td>
</tr>
```

it throws an error, that game.theAds is undefined, but game.name is set correctly.

Could please somone help me?

Greetings Mickey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's because it is too late to try to get data from relationships in js. You should get this data before 'eloquent models' convert to JSON

```
$games = Game::where(['id' => auth()->user()->current_team_id])->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->with('theAds')
->get()
->map(function ($e) {
                $e->theAds = $e->theAds;
                return $e;
             })
```

Or you can create 'ResourceCollection' that help convert 'eloquent models collection' to JSON and then you can be able to access related data
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! I will try this out on saturday and check if it works (i work on this prototype only on weekends and sometimes on evenings)